# How to create layout that same with layout in this picture in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to create a layout show image box and text box in front of the image boxes in the same with the layout in this picture:

[image: image1]

Thank you very much.

```css
.issue_item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
}

.issue_item.not_image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #FF3800;
}

.issue_item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.issue_item .issue_item_image {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>B BRAND</th>
      <th>C BRAND</th>
      <th>D BRAND</th>
      <th>E BRAND</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item not_image"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/MPQ6ww8/B-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/9HhhhV7/C-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/9vvRdQP/D-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/n6RFPLL/E-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I might try using a flexbox instead of a table.

```
.issue_item{
       flex: 1 0 0;
    }
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex-container"
    <div class="issue_item not_image"></div>    
    <div class="issue_item">
        <div>B BRAND</div>
        <img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/MPQ6ww8/B-Brand.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="issue_item">
        <div>C BRAND</div>
        <img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/9HhhhV7/C-Brand.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="issue_item">
        <div>D BRAND</div>
        <img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/9vvRdQP/D-Brand.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="issue_item">
        <div>c BRAND</div>
        <img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/n6RFPLL/E-Brand.png"/>
    </div>
```

The text bubbles in front can be positioned using

```
position:absolute
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.issue_row>th {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.issue_table {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.issue_item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
}

.issue_item_image {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.issue_item.not_image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #FF3800;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="issue_table">

  <tbody>
    <tr class="issue_row">
      <th></th>
      <th>B BRAND</th>

      <th>C BRAND</th>

      <th>D BRAND</th>
      <th>E BRAND</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item not_image"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/MPQ6ww8/B-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/9HhhhV7/C-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/9vvRdQP/D-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="issue_item"><img class="issue_item_image" src="https://i.ibb.co/n6RFPLL/E-Brand.png" /></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's how you do it. You can also check this [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpksL0xe/17/)

Comment: Thank you. But I want to it responsive. How to create it responsive

Comment: Using table is not the best option to make it responsive. You can try Flex. Or since you are using bootstrap you can easily do it with their `row` and `col`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap5, this already work with display flex. So, no need for any extra CSS.
Just try this one-

```
<div id="section" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 bg-active d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center p-4">
                <h1 class="text-light">Some<br>Content<br>Here</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h4 class="text-center p-2 mb-0 bg-dark text-light">B Brand</h4>
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/MPQ6ww8/B-Brand.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h4 class="text-center p-2 mb-0 bg-active text-light">C Brand</h4>
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/MPQ6ww8/C-Brand.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h4 class="text-center p-2 mb-0 bg-dark text-light">D Brand</h4>
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/MPQ6ww8/D-Brand.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is some little css-

```
#section {
        background-color: #fe0;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    #section .box img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    #section .container>.row {
        border: 4px solid #000;
    }
    #section .container>.row .box {
        border-left: 4px solid #000;
    }
    #section .bg-active {
        background-color: #FF3800;
    }
```